# How to make sure a user enters a number or else a loop will continue

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I am having trouble validating my users input. I need the code to keep asking 'what is offset' unless a number is entered. if letters spaces special characters are entered it should cause the question to be asked again.

```
while True:
    offset=int(raw_input('what is offset (decimals will be ignored)'))
    if offset >=0 and offset<=26:
        break
```

Comment: So what's the problem?  Is it that the user can type in 3.0 and that will throw an exception?

Comment: Oh i meant to say if a letter or anything other than a number is entered it will throw an error, i want it to loop and keep asking until a number is entered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while True:
    try:
      offset=int(raw_input('what is offset (decimals will be ignored)'))
      if offset >=0 and offset<=26:
        break
    except ValueError:
      pass
```

(In other words, if raw_input throws an exception, skip it as long as it's ValueError (so a user could e.g. still hit control-c to quit the application)

Comment: its a good suggestion but im required to have it loop if a user enters something wrong thanks anyway

Comment: I'm confused ... this will loop if the user enters something wrong (the flow will be: enter while loop, enter try, call int(raw_input) which trhows the exception, except ValueError will catch it, pass will cause it to continue, which then brings you back up to the while loop)

Comment: Oh sorry about that i tried it and it works perfectly thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what its doing

Comment: I would prefer to set `user_input = input("The prompt for the user here")` before the try and only have the conversion, so `offset = int(user_input)`, inside the try block to make clear that only that conversion is the part that can throw an exception.
It's also possible to replace the `pass` with `continue` and move the `if offset >= ...` after/outside the try except, just normally inside the while loop. To make clear this is the next validation and doesn't have anything to do with the try except anymore really.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this code?

```
'''
question.py
'''

#define function

def question():

    import sys

    #try to get get a number
    try:
        #get input from user
        offset = int(raw_input('what is offset? (decimals will be ignored) '))
        if offset >=0 and offset <=26:
            print offset
        else:question()
    #all other exceptions
    except:
        question()
        #sys.exit(1)#abort

#run program
question = question()
```

Comment: If the poster had asked how to do it without a loop, I guess I could understand... but otherwise, this use of recursion doesn't make a whole lot of sense... for at least some versions of python, a determined idiot should be able to get this to throw stackoverflow, and while that's the name of the site, it's probably not desirable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I aspire to code clean, it is my knowledge of python that is inferior.